# How do I split a string with special characters into a NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, special-characters, unichar

I'am trying to seperate a string with danish characters into a NSMutableArray. But something is not working. :(

My code:

```
NSString *danishString = @"æøå";

NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[danishString length]]; 

for (int i=0; i < [danishString length]; i++) 
{ 
     NSString *ichar = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [danishString characterAtIndex:i ]]; 
     [characters addObject:ichar]; 
}
```

If I do at NSLog on the danishString it works (returns æøå);

But if I do a NSLog on the characters (the array) I get some very stange characters - What is wrong?

/Morten

Comment: It's too bad whoever down voted everything in this thread, because IMO this is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code is incorrect. `characterAtIndex` returns `unichar`, so you should use `@"%C"`(uppercase) as the format specifier.

Even with the correct format specifier, your code is unsafe, and strictly speaking, still incorrect, because not all unicode characters can be represented by a single `unichar`. You should always handle unicode strings per substring:

> It's common to think of a string as a sequence of characters, but when
>   working with NSString objects, or with Unicode strings in general, in
>   most cases it is better to deal with substrings rather than with
>   individual characters. The reason for this is that what the user
>   perceives as a character in text may in many cases be represented by
>   multiple characters in the string.

You should definitely read [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i).

Finally, the correct code for you:

```
NSString *danishString = @"æøå";
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[danishString length]]; 
[danishString enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, danishString.length) options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [characters addObject:substring];
}];
```

If with `NSLog(@"%@", characters);` you see "strange character" of the form "\Uxxxx", that's correct. It's the default stringification behavior of `NSArray` by `description` method. You can print these unicode characters one by one if you want to see the "normal characters":

```
for (NSString *c in characters) {
    NSLog(@"%@", c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `ichar` isn't type of `NSString`, but `unichar`. If you want `NSString`s try getting a substring instead :

```
NSString *danishString = @"æøå";
NSMutableArray *characters = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[danishString length]]; 

for (int i=0; i < [danishString length]; i++) 
{ 
    NSRange r = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
    NSString *ichar = [danishString substringWithRange:r]; 
    [characters addObject:ichar]; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following, which should be fine with Danish characters, but would break down if you have decomposed characters. I suggest reading the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/introStrings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000035i) for more information.

```
NSString *danishString = @"æøå";
NSMutableArray* characters = [NSMutableArray array];
for( int i = 0; i < [danishString length]; i++ ) {
  NSString* subchar = [danishString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
  if( subchar ) [characters addObject:subchar];
}
```

That would split the string into an array of individual characters, assuming that all the code points were composed characters.

Answer (score -1):

It is printing the unicode of the characters. Anyhow, you can use the unicode (with \u) anywhere.